# Edit multiple html files - add string to <head>

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, notepad++

i have huge static html site and i need to add some new script and css path at the end of each head section. Is there any tool which can help me in that ?.

Or maybe i can use some php or JS? I'm quite new in this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could then use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to add this code to every file.

Open Notepad++, open search -> replace (or `ctrl + H`)
Go to the 'find in files' tab
Find `</head>`
Replace it with:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" rel="style.css">
</head>
```

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-and-replace-words-in-multiple-files/

---

You can also use php includes.

Have an html file with the script and css in, for example:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" rel="style.css">
```

Put any html code you want on every page, in one file and call it, say, `include.html`

Then use this php code in any file you want that code:

```
<?php
    include('include.html');
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still require an edit to each individual HTML file?

Comment: Well yes, but you could use a tool such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to add this code to every file: http://cybernetnews.com/find-replace-multiple-files/

Comment: But isn't it just find and replace ? Is there some tool which can add new string ?

Comment: See my updated answer: find `</head>` and replace it with `your code`, then `</head>` @Ganga

Comment: Solution looks good, but notepad ++ don't allow to use enter and paste in replace tab  - i need to write it by hand and also, after that code is a mess :)

Comment: Ok, try this tool: https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/ It allows you to *"Find and replace multi-line text"* @Ganga

Comment: at the end , this solution works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add CSS and JS files dynamically to a page's `<head>`, then use  the following function.

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}


loadjscssfile("javascript.js", "js");
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css");
```

Comment: Sounds good , but how can i use it in static html site to return this on in each file ?

Comment: @Ganga I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, how can i actually make this function work in my project which have only .html files. Just add this function to index ? .

Comment: @Ganga well in that case this doesn't help much I think. Or you can try adding this in side any of the common js files the html pages are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to do it in javascript, you could do something like this:

CSS:

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var cssNode = document.createElement('link');
cssNode.type = 'text/css';
cssNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
cssNode.href = 'http://some.url.com/style.css'
cssNode.media = 'screen';
headID.appendChild(cssNode);
```

JS:

```
var s    = document.createElement('script');
s.type   = 'text/javascript';
s.async  = true;
s.src    = 'http://some.url.com/script.js';
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called TextReplacerv1.4e which will search multiple files for specific text and allow you to replace it.  In your case, you could search for: `</head>` and replace it with:

```
<new script here>
<new css here>
</head>
```

You can Google to find TextReplacerv1.4e

Edited to add:  Actually, I don't find TextReplacerv1.4e available anymore.  Here is a tool that works similarly: http://www.ecobyte.com/replacetext/

Comment: @Ganga, I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For any javascript source files:

```
<script src="YOUR_SCRIPT_PATH_HERE.js"></script>
```

For including CSS sheets in any heading:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved your problem in a semi-systematic fashion. However, for posteriority, the right tool for this kind of problem is **Sed** from the GNU tool set. The fact that you are using Notepad++ rules out that you are on a Unix environment. [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) is supposed to be a good option for getting some of the basic GNU/Linux tools for Windows.

Once you have Sed, you can do:

```
 sed 's/<\/head>/line1\nline2\n/<\/head>/' *.html -i
```

You can change `*.html` to the filenames you have. The option `-i` allows to save directly to the files instead of outputting to `stdout`. `\n` is of course a new line.